# Pegar conteúdos de div's dentro de um HTML

Tags: php, html

Como faço pra pegar todos os valores que tem dentro de `<div class='conteudo'></div>`?

Já tentei assim:

```
$links = "<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 1</div>
</li></ul>
<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 2</div>
</li></ul>
<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 3</div>
</li></ul>
<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 4</div>
</li></ul>";

$conteudo2 = explode('</li>', $links);

foreach($conteudo2 as $key) {    
    echo ''.$key.'';    
}
```

Mas ele pega todo o conteúdo das tags, não só o valor de dentro da `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema de usar [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) é que ele quebra a string sem levar em conta a semântica do HTML (ou seja, o significado de cada *tag*, a separação entre o que é uma *tag* e o que é o conteúdo da mesma, etc).

Para manipular um conteúdo HTML da forma que você precisa, você pode usar [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```php
$links = "<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 1</div>
</li></ul>
<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 2</div>
</li></ul>
<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 3</div>
</li></ul>
<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 4</div>
</li></ul>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($links);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// procura elementos div com classe "conteudo"
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="conteudo"]') as $div) {
    echo $div->textContent. "<br>";
}
```

Assim, eu procuro por todos os elementos `div` que possuem a classe "conteudo" (usando a sintaxe de [XPATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)), e imprimo seus respectivos valores. A saída do código acima é:

```
CORPO 1
CORPO 2
CORPO 3
CORPO 4
```

---

O código acima funciona se dentro da `div` só tiver um texto simples. Mas se dentro da `div` tiver outras *tags* e você quer todo este conteúdo, você precisa usar uma função auxiliar para obter o HTML do conteúdo interno (a função abaixo foi tirada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087136)):

```php
$links = "<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 1</div>
</li></ul>
<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'>CORPO 2</div>
</li></ul>
<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'><p>CORPO 3 <span>teste com <strong>outras tags</strong></span> dentro do div</p></div>
</li></ul>
<ul><li>CONTEUDO
<div class='conteudo'><span>CORPO 4</span></div>
</li></ul>";

function innerHTML(DOMNode $element) { 
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children  = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
        $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
    }
    return $innerHTML; 
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($links);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="conteudo"]') as $div) {
    echo innerHTML($div). "<br>";
}
```

A saída é:

```
CORPO 1
CORPO 2
<p>CORPO 3 <span>teste com <strong>outras tags</strong></span> dentro do div</p>
<span>CORPO 4</span>
```

Comment: mas no caso se tiver <div class='conteudo'><span>CORPO 2</span></div> não teria como pegar <span>CORPO2</span>? pq testei só pega CORPO 2

Comment: @RogérioSilva Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Ta tudo ok, mas sabe pq quando algo no CORPO tem o caractere &, aparece um erro DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity?

Comment: @RogérioSilva Porque o `&` tem significado especial no HTML, é usado para [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) (se tem um `&` "solto" no texto, está errado). Mas aí já está fugindo do escopo da pergunta (que é como obter o conteúdo de determinada tag). De qualquer forma, se o texto tem que ter um `&`, o correto é escrevê-lo como `&amp;`